# Combing columns with replacement based on value

Tags: r, replace, multiple-columns

I am trying to combine 2 or more different columns, with the replacement of values. For example,

```
a      b

1     0
1     1
<NA>  1
0     1
0     0
```

would become

```
c

1     
1     
1
1    
0
```

Most functions seem to have an index column, which would be different from having and overwriting value.

Is there a possible way to combine with replacement according to value?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "with replacement", but at least in this example `c = as.integer(a | b)`. Also `c = pmax(a, b, na.rm = TRUE)`. If you can be more specific what your operation perhaps we can help more.

Comment: I also don't know what you mean by "most functions seem to have an index column"... what functions are you talking about? Do you mean "an index argument"?

Answer (score 1):

We could do it with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  #mutate(c = ifelse(is.na(a) | a ==1, 1, b))
  transmute(c = ifelse(is.na(a) | a ==1, 1, b))
```

```
 c
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 0
```